# Use a list across different files in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a hard-coded list that I have to use across many Python files.

I tried doing something like(Say the list is in xyz.py)

```
global l=list() 
class abc:
    def __init__(self):
        l=[12,13,4] #values assigned
```

How can I access it in other Python files?

Comment: Import the list: `from xyz import l`. Note that your `global` used like that does nothing.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense; what are you *actually* trying to achieve? Note that the `l` in `abc.__init__` is **not** global.

Comment: @jonrsharpe OP tried this way, what he want to achieve is to access the list `l` in other files.

Comment: @salmanwahed yes, thank you, I can read what the OP wrote, but that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @poke looks like you answered the question in comment itself :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to achieve is something like the following:

**file1.py**

```
from file2 import my_list

print(my_list)
```

**file2.py**

```
my_list = []

class abc:
    def __init__(self):
        global my_list

        my_list = [12,13,4] #values assigned


my_abc_file2 = abc()
```

Running `file1.py` would give:

```
[12, 13, 4]
```

As mentioned in the comments, `file2.py` really only needs to contain the following for it to work though:

**file2.py**

```
my_list = [12,13,4]
```

Tested in Python 2.7

Comment: Why create that class and object though?

Comment: What poke said. "file2.py" only needs to contain `my_list = [12,13,4]`

Comment: Agreed it is definitely not needed, but it does show how the example could have been made to work.